# A textbox accept four numbers and two decimals using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
In HTML page a text box accept only the following format: `7898.90`

Using JQuery..

 Four numbers and dot(.) after that two numbers
Textbox maximum length is 7. like,  `$("#Future").attr('maxlength', '7');` 


   if (charCode != 44 && charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    if (charCode != 37 && charCode != 38 && charCode != 39 && charCode != 40) {
        var val = event.key;
        if (AdHocScript.isAlphabet(val)) {
            return false;
        }
```

Can  any one explain .. In HTML page a text box accept only the following format: `7898.90`

```
Using JQuery..

 Four numbers and dot(.) after that two numbers
Textbox maximum length is 7. like,  `$("#Future").attr('maxlength', '7');` 
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: please, post the input code, but I pretty sure you have to use regex or patter

Comment: You can use masking for this. Some plugins are there, sometimes you might find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995998/masked-input-plugin-and-regular-expressions-for-decimal-numbers http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/ check the examples in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#Future').keypress(function (event) {
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        var text = $(this).val();

        if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)
             || (text.length > 7)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.. its working. after completion of entering number,if  i delete a number  it is deleting but it not inserting another number

Answer (score 0):

First u set max length for your text box as 7. And call key press event. In that function get key code for each char entered by user, allow only 'dot' then reset max length as '2'.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumKey(evt)" maxlength ="7" />

 function isNumKey(evt) {

    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;


    if (charCode > 31 ....){ // here restrict all other special char 
        return false;
    }
    else if(charCode === 46){ // key code for dot(.)
        if((dotcount === 0)&&(maxlen<=7)){
               dotcount = ++dotcount;
               $('#..').attr("maxlength", pointPos+3); //pointPos initially set as length of the text box
               return true;
        }
       return false;
    }       
}
```

try this u  can get idea to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I posted this before any code was provided in the Question. May help anyone else with a different implementation.

You should do this using regex. Here is a sample: 
The jsfiddle implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/3v6gcjzx/1/

Bascially, you want to validate on the textbox blur event to check the regex expression for 4 digits a decimal and 2 more digits (as an example) using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#text1").on('blur', function () {
        var regexExp = /[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}/
        alert(regexExp.test(($('#text1').val())) ? "valid input" : "invalid input");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("keypress", "#txtbox", "", function (event) {
    var check = $(this).val().indexOf('.');
     if (check < 0) {
         if ($(this).val().length < 4 || event.keyCode == 46) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     } else {
         if ($(this).val().length >= check && $(this).val().length < check + 3 && event.keyCode != 46) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     }
});
```

Eg:1234.23

Comment: please add a explanation to your answer!